# android option menu: how to organize it to 2 lines?

Tags: android

I want my option menu to be display in 2 lines, but I tried to use LinearLayout in menu.xml to contain the MenuItem, the debugger report errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options menu sizes automatically depending on the number of menu items you've added. You get a second row if you add more than three items.